# Deploying Websharper Application from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: f#, websharper

So as a beginner to the entire Visual Studio IDE and a beginner to F# and the F# based WebSharper, I have certain issues on the system. I use the 'Ctrl+F5' to test the application. Now what do I do if I want to package the application and deploy it on another server, say apache server? Assuming the basic example [here](http://www.websharper.com/docs/getting-started) has just the .js files and HTML files, where do I find the generated web pages and/or .js files or how do I generate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you created the application using the HTML Site template you’ll find the HTML bundle in the project’s bin folder. You can deploy WebSharper applications built using this template on any server you prefer. If you used one of the Web Application templates (Sitelets, ASP.NET, …) you have the choice between Windows hosting and [following these instructions to host the application using Mono on a Linux box running nginx](http://thecodedecanter.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/hosting-websharperasp-net-apps-on-linux-with-mono-nginx/).

When it comes to Windows hosting, AppHarbor is a great choice for deploying WebSharper apps and you can use one of these two templates which both build on AppHarbor to jumpstart your project:

- [WebSharperMVC](https://github.com/TahaHachana/WebSharperMVC)
- [WebSharperBootstrap](https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper-bootstrap-site)

Comment: So I used the Sitelets. Is AppHarbor the only way to see the built projects? As an analogy, lets say I build a java web project using the eclipse IDE. I can use a tomcat container to deploy the files and also I can see the generated files. Later I can also package all the files to a war. Something like just using Visual Studio to deploy to IIS?

Comment: AppHarbor is one option among others for deploying a Sitelets app. VS offers 4 methods for deploying a web application: Web Deploy, FTP, File system and FPSE. You can read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.100).aspx) to learn how to use Web Deploy in order to publish your application.